# How to work with JSON in pig?

Tags: json, apache-pig

If i have a text file with JSON, how do I load and store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using JSONLoader and JSONStorage to load and store the json data, its included in Pig from 0.10.0

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#jsonloadstore